# How to debug a Flutter app in release mode after restart?

Tags: flutter, debugging, release-mode

I'm developing a Flutter App that uses deep links.

To test the behavior when the app is closed I do a `flutter run --release` so the app is installed on my iPhone, then I can close the app and open it with the deep link.

Something is not working as I expect, but how can I debug this? I don't have any kind of log, so how can I debug my app to solve my issue?

Comment: You dont need to quit/close the app. just press the back button and now the app is run in background. then open the app by clicking the deep link.